# Usage des traits d'union dans les toponymes

Tags: noms-propres, trait-d-union

Sur certaines pages Wikipédia, j'ai remarqué une utilisation qui me semble exagérée des traits d'union dans les noms propres. Pour citer quelques exemples :

- [La page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170616070923/https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canal-du-Midi_(m%C3%A9tro_de_Toulouse)) de la station de métro "Canal du Midi" à Toulouse, intitulée "Canal-du-Midi"
- Les pages des trois universités ([I](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319204028/https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%C3%A9_Toulouse-I-Capitole), [II](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408164616/https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%C3%A9_Toulouse-Jean-Jaur%C3%A8s), [III](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319204028/https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%C3%A9_Toulouse-III-Paul-Sabatier)) de Toulouse remplacent les espaces dans le nom de l'institution par des traits d'union

Existe-il des règles particulières au sujet de l'usage des traits d'union pour les noms propres ? Le genre d'utilisation dans les exemples cités est-il correct ?

Comment: Où est le mal ? La station de métro de Toulouse à quoi à voir avec un canal , avec du et avec midi ?

Comment: Au demeurant... je trouve l'interrogation sur la *correction* superflue. Si une autorité nomme un truc *bidulchmuche-machin* c'est **forcément** correct! (Par définition du mot *autorité*).

Comment: Sauf que l'autorité ne nomme pas la station comme ça, c'est un usage non "officiel".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cet usage est conforme à la pratique reconnue par diverses autorités et il peut être vérifié en quelque détail sur cet [article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_d%27union#R%C3%A8gles_typographiques_traditionnelles_fran%C3%A7aises).

Dans la dénomination du canal il faudra écrire « le canal du Midi »; toute réattribution du nom doit comporter des traits d'union : la station Canal-du-Midi. Comme dans l'article que vous citez il s'agit de la station, même si le mot « station » ne précède pas le nom, il faut des traits d'union et ainsi que spécifié dans la référence, il faut que les mots commencent par des capitales (sauf les mots grammaticaux).

Answer (score 4):

Selon [Le lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale) à propos des noms de rues (applicable, à mon avis, aux stations de métro), on doit mettre des traits d'union entre tous les éléments d'un nom composé,  l'exception de l'article initial.

Par exemple :

- l'avenue de la Porte-des-Lilas.
- la rue du Chat-qui-Pêche.
- le pont Neuf.
- la place Rouge.

Dans le cas en question, on doit donc écrire :

> La station Canal-du-Midi.

Extrait du document sus-cité :

[image]

Comment: Peux-tu fermer la parenthèse que tu as ouverte stp, je me sens mal.

Comment: @Destal: c'est fait, merci.

Comment: Merci je me sens beaucoup mieux. Super document au passage.